# spring boot: separate application properties into multiple property files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are having a spring boot application composed of 34 "modules".

In front of these 34 "modules", a web controller is dispatching the requests to the appropriate modules.

- Each module share a common public interface on which the controller is coupled
- Each module is a specific java package under which will be assembled the required java class and resources to have the module working.
- Each module are independent and do not rely on another module
- Each module are relatively small (5 to 10 java classes relying on 5 to 20 environment-relative properties)

**My question would be: what would be the best approach to have one property file by module?**

My concerns:

- These modules are independent, decoupled, and segmented. With the same idea, I would like their properties to be the same (ie: one property file by module)
- Right now these properties are retrieved from the classpath, but eventually, I would like them to be retrieved from a configuration server (ie: spring cloud config server)
- I like the spring boot configuration capabilities and would like to stay with it (this is something standard, there is a lot of documentation around it and a lot of people know how it works)
- I would like to avoid "customizing" the spring boot configuration system (ie: extending classes, etc). This will not be standard anymore and migrating to a new version of spring will be more complicated.

What I have thought so far:

#### First idea: one spring profile per module

1) under application.yml, all module profile can be listed:

```
spring.profiles.include:
  - module1
  - module2
  - modulex
  - module34
```

2) one properties file per module can be created

application-module1.yml

```
# environment agnostic properties

module1.property1: environmentAgnostic

---

spring.profiles: prd
module1.property2: prd-value

---
spring.profiles: stg
module1.property2: stg-value
```

**Pros:**
This allow to have one properties file by module

**Cons:**
I don't feel that spring profiles were built for this. 100% of the time, all the modules will be actives, my understanding is that spring profiles were built to change the behavior of the application by activating or deactivating a specific profile at boot time.

#### Second idea: Create one spring boot application by module

**Pros:** 
This allow to have one properties file by module (by spring boot application)

**Cons:**
Create a lot of overhead and not cost-effective in term of resources. 34 spring boot application running in parallel (2 instances per environment for 2 environments) will cost a lot for not so much value.

#### Third idea: Using @PropertySource

```
@PropertySource( "module1.yml")
@Configuration
public class Module1Configuration
{
}
```

**Blocker:** 
Not working with spring cloud config service (unless there is something I am missing?)

#### Any other ideas or suggestions?

- It seems that by not offering that capability spring boot does not suggest to split the properties into multiple property files.
- Does what I am trying to archive is considered as an "anti-pattern"?
- Does it exists another standard way then spring boot configuration capabilities to handle that kind of pattern? (ie: an external java library that is widely used in the industry)
- Other?

Comment: It sounds like you are planning to pull all the modules together and deploy them as a single application. If I’ve got that right, I can’t see the benefit of having one deployable unit but 30+ files to configure it. Why not configure the application with a single file?

Comment: The result would be about more than 500 properties in one file per environment. My personal point of view would be that splitting the properties by module (in different files) would enhance cohesion and the independences of these modules.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Andy in this matter; there's generally very little value to be gained by splitting up the configuration into even more files. You could always use `@ConfigurationProperties` to keep your properties separate from one another. Something along the lines of:

**application.yml:**

```
myapp:
  module1:
    my-first-property: somevalue
    my-second-property: someothervalue
  module2:
    my-third-property: somethirdvalue
    my-fourth-property: somefourthvalue
  # however many modules you want...
```

**Module1Properties.java**

```java
@Data // Lombok shorthand for setters and getters, etc.
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.module1")
public class Module1Properties {
    private String myFirstProperty;
    private String mySecondProperty;
}
```

**Module2Properties.java**

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.module2")
public class Module2Properties {
    private String myThirdProperty;
    private String myFourthProperty;
}
```

Comment: This seems a good approach to me . Why ? 1. By separating in multiple properties file, we will achieve less, rather it will add clutter and maintainnence issues. 2. Single properties file is more convenient in this case. 3. We are achieving partial separation of concern by using a hierarchical approach ( ex : @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.module2")) .